# Summarise columns and identify columns where value is not equal to 100

Tags: r

I have this Dataframe called `Wild_animals` that looks as following:

```
Animal    2000    2001  2002  2003  2004  2005  2006  2007
Cat        25      40    20     0     51    15   85    0
Dog        25      15    20     0     48    46    5    0
Fox        25      12    20     0      0    15    5    0
Tiger      10      21    20     0      0    15    1    0
Lion        5       7    20    100     1    40    4    0
```

What I'm trying to figure out is to summarise each row so I can determine through R if there is 100 animals that year, or above or below that.

The tibble should look something like this:

```
2000   2001  2002  2003  2004  2005  2006  2007
 90     95    100   100   100   131   100    0
```

Comment: `colSums(Wild_animals[, -1])`

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  summarise(across(2:ncol(.), sum))

# A tibble: 1 x 8
  `2000` `2001` `2002` `2003` `2004` `2005` `2006` `2007`
   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     90     95    100    100    100    131    100      0
```

Tidy format

```
df %>% 
  summarise(across(2:ncol(.), sum)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(), 
               names_to = "year",
               values_to = "sum")

# A tibble: 8 x 2
  year    sum
  <chr> <dbl>
1 2000     90
2 2001     95
3 2002    100
4 2003    100
5 2004    100
6 2005    131
7 2006    100
8 2007      0
```